# Visual Studio 2017: Connection to IBM.Data.DB2 fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, informix

I'm actually trying to connect my MVC application to an Informix Database. In Visual Studio 2015 I made this work, but after I lifted my project to Visual Studio 2017 the connection (update model out of database) fails. It looks like the 2017 project isn't able to find the necessary `IBM.Data.DB2`. In the first place I am also not able to create a connection to an IBM database in Visual Studio 2017.

It is really hard to describe my actual problem, so if there are any open questions, please ask.

And thank you for your help.

Comment: Let's start with *"not able to create a connection"*... please edit your question to include the connection string (anonymized as needed), the code that attempts to make the connection (minimal but complete), and the exception details when it fails.

Comment: Did you add the reference `IBM.Data.DB2` by steps `Project->Manage Nuget Packages`?

Comment: @madreflection There is no connection string and no code, because I'm trying to connect directly via Visual Studio. The error message by Visual Studio describes a `System.Argument.Exception` and is unfortunately in german...

Comment: @KyleWang I added the reference, but it doesn't help.

Comment: If you're trying to connect *"directly via Visual Studio"* (such as with Server Explorer), then your question has nothing to do with the tags [tag:asp.net-mvc], [tag:model-view-controller], or even [tag:c#], and your description that includes *"trying to connect my MVC application"* is misleading because it suggests that the error is happening in your own code.

Comment: @madreflection Okay sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the DB2 connection client and apply a license to it.

[DB2 clients and drivers](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-initial-version-115-clients-and-drivers)

Comment: I think I already have installed the DB2 connection, but is there any way to test it?
What do you mean by applying a license to it?

Comment: It worked with the linked files. Probably my installations were outdated. Thank you!

Comment: You probably already have installed the license for it, glad it helped